# How do I order multiple items from my database on the same row?

Tags: html, django

I want to have four items from my database listed on the same row, as of now, my code is putting a break between each item.

```
{% if latest_shoop_list %}
{% for shoop in latest_shoop_list %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src='images/{{ shoop.shoop_image }}' width='250'/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src='images/{{ shoop.shoop_image }}' width='250'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Then loop inside the table, not outside of it, as with the implementation you have you create a different table for each `shoop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the table and row tags out of for loop.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    {% for shoop in latest_shoop_list %}
            <td>
                <img src='images/{{ shoop.shoop_image }}' width='250'/>
            </td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```